# Reasons of aggressive cat and even not playing at all!

Tags: cats, behavior, training, animal-handling

My cat is around 2 years old. Its Persian male cat. He has no any partner.

I don't know what's the problem with it! It is not playing at all, also it is not responding to my voice (except there is something which he really wants like food, opening door when he wants to go outside). Also, it is very aggressive when we try to play with him, few times he has attacked me with a horrible voice. I was so scared.!

How can I help him to get normal again? And what can be the causes for such problem? He is with me even when he was 3 weeks old!

Do I need to spend more time with him? Or he really needs a partner? Or he wants to go out? Or he is bored from me and even don't want to be with me?   :( or there is some other issue with him?

Your help will be highly appreciable

Comment: When was he last checked by a vet? He may be in pain and therefore doesn't like to play anymore and even attack you if you unknowingly hurt him while petting him.

Comment: Even yesterday, vet has examined him. But didn't find any symbol of physical pain. He is totally okay. But the change in his behavior seriously disturb me!

Comment: Even he has shouted on vet yesterday, with a horrible voice, when he was trying to insert the injection. While before that, he never make any kind of voice while injection or vaccination

Answer (score 2):

Wow I'm sorry to hear that and can relate in a way with my kitten right now. Is there any way she could have been attacked ? Or abused? I've seen similar situations where the cat was attacked and I felt like he no longer felt safe. And I also know that abuse can def cause similar issues . It could have been a situation where you were completely unaware . Things  like a small child holding him down , throwing him etc . Those things can really break trust with a cat. I find it interesting that he is being so aggressive and I feel like something must have happened. Can you think of any time around the change where he got outside and may have attacked ? Or had family in town and the niece that does not get disciplined stayed over night ? Anyways I hope it helps and I wish you luck!!

Comment: I am noticing the behavior of my cat since last 3 months. I don't let him go outside due to other wild cats (who are always ready to fight). But few months ago, he was mistakenly go out, and I didn't find him for 2 months. I don't know, what happens with him in that duration, but symptoms can be observed after that.